# How to automatically run Code First Migrations on DB when using WebDeploy to publish web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to have my SQL database auto-update using Code First Migrations when I publish my web app to Azure.

So far I have a publish profile working that does copy the application to the remote Azure server but the Database is not Updating when I publish the app. If I run the Update-Database command directly from the Package Manager Console it updates the Remote DB but it does not work if I use the profile. I was reading a tutorial step by step from Microsoft that dates back to 2014 that suggest I enable Use Code First Migrations on the publish profile, but that is not an option in Visual Studio Community 2015 and Code First Migrations is already setup in my application.

Any idea how to run Code First Migrations when I publish my app via web deploy?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true` in your db config ?

Comment: Erkan Demirel Thanks for your repsonse, yes automaticmigrationsenabled is set to true in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

This article walks you through step by step on exactly how to do this.

Its an older article but the same concepts and instructions still apply.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/04/08/ef-code-first-migrations-deployment-to-an-azure-cloud-service/